# Jung graph straight parallel edges

Tags: java, graph, jung

Does Jung provide parallel straight edges without overlapping them?
I want to obtain something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b5nh.png)

Is it possible to obtain this functionality without using QuadCurve/CubicCurve lines?

Comment: Please don't use the 'jung2' tag.  It doesn't carry any additional information than the 'jung' tag does.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own edge shapes as is done in EdgeShape.java; specifically I would look at how BentLine is defined, since it would be fairly easy to modify to do something like what you want:

https://github.com/jrtom/jung/blob/master/jung-visualization/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/jung/visualization/decorators/EdgeShape.java#L141

In particular, I wouldn't actually recommend using 2+ parallel straight lines as edges, because it's cleaner when the endpoints of the lines are all at the same place (and this is what the visualization and rendering code assumes).  If you want the lines to be basically straight, use lines that are straight for most of their length and then bend at each end to meet at the endpoint, e.g.:

```
int index = getIndex(e, edgeIndexFunction);
float controlY = control_offset_increment + control_offset_increment * index;
BENT_LINE.reset();
BENT_LINE.moveTo(0.0f, 0.0f);
BENT_LINE.lineTo(0.1f, controlY);
BENT_LINE.lineTo(0.9f, controlY);
BENT_LINE.lineTo(1.0f, 1.0f);
return BENT_LINE;
```

Comment: yep, it worked. I used something similar with EdgeShape.LINE, modifying the parameters of Line2D.Float(...) when drawing the second parallel line.